# Build error in OpenWRT

Tags: networking, openwrt

I followed the following steps given on the OpenWrt website to setup the OpenWrt build system.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install git-core build-essential libssl-dev libncurses5-dev unzip gawk zlib1g-dev`

`git clone https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt.git`

`git clone -b chaos_calmer git://github.com/openwrt/openwrt.git`

`cd openwrt
./scripts/feeds update -a
./scripts/feeds install -a`

I made the necessary changes in the configuration file and ran the `make` command. It gives the following error: make: *** [world] Error 1

Any solutions?

Comment: The information provided is insufficient. You need to tell how and what configuration file(s) you changed.

Comment: check the new wiki page https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/build-system/install-buildsystem

Answer (score 0):

use following command options to know the exact error you are getting

```
make -j1 V=s
```

Sometimes due to slow internet speed(while fetching package source code for openwrt) or due to less RAM availability or wrong configuration leads to this error. Post the error message block you are getting, to understand more about the problem.

Comment: `make -d --debug=j` would also help in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Please, follow up the following prerequisities:
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/buildroot.exigence

Take a look especially at the table "Table of known prerequisites and their corresponding packages".

Answer (score 0):

You have to install version7 of gcc and g++ so Try this:

```
sudo apt install gcc-7 g++-7 build-essential
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 7
```